# Ajax script loading/Displaying only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This script displaying the dynamic content for once thereafter its not working

Here is the code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.getmore').on('click',function(){
                var last_id = $(this).attr('id');   
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url : 'http://localhost/tech1/services/getmore.php',    
                    data: 'last_id='+last_id,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('.getmore').html('<img src="../images/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />');  
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.getmore').remove();
                        $('#comments').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }); 
        });
```

Here is the complete php code:

```
        <?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Error... Couldnt connect..');
    mysql_select_db('mydb') or die('Error... Couldnt select the Db..');

        $records = mysql_query(' SELECT * FROM `compare_post_comments` WHERE `post_id`=37 limit 5 ');
         if(mysql_num_rows($records)){
             echo '<div id="ajax_comment">';
            echo '<ul id="comments">';
            while($data = @mysql_fetch_array($records) ){
                echo '<li>'.$data['comments'].'</li>';
                $last_record = $data['sno'];
            }
            echo '<li class="getmore" id="'.$last_record.'">Get More</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
            echo "<span id='cmmnts'></span>";
            echo '</div>';
         }
    ?>
```

getmore.php code

```
    <?php

if( ( isset($_POST['last_id'])!=null ) && $_POST['last_id']!="" ){
    $last_id = $_POST['last_id'];
    //echo "::".$last_id;
    $qry = " SELECT * FROM `compare_post_comments` WHERE `post_id`=37 and sno > ".$last_id." limit 5 ";
    //echo "::".$qry;
    $comments = mysql_query($qry) or die('Error..');
    if( mysql_num_rows($comments) ){
        while( $data = mysql_fetch_array($comments) ){
            echo "<li>".$data['comments']."</li>";
            $last_id=$data['sno'];
        }
        echo "<li class='getmore' id='".$last_id."'>Get More</li>";
    }else{
        echo "<li class='nomore'>No More</li>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<li class='nomore'>No More</li>";
}
```

?>

ajax call working for once, thereafter its not clickable.
I dont have much knowledge about ajax and javascript, explanation is appreciated.

Comment: any error in cosole??

Comment: Why it should be called once more? You are removing element $('.getmore') after first ajax call...

Comment: @JustinasJurciukonis May be the variable `data` have that element

Comment: @rynhe: That is what I assumed too, but of course the HTML example is not provided.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the HTML before and after a load? It is not clear whether the `getmore' class exists in the dynamically loaded data.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar No error on console.

Comment: @JustinasJurciukonis How to get ajax call for multiple times??

Comment: @Fastnto loop with ajax calls or don't delete element, so you can click on in again

Comment: It appears you are indeed recreating the `class='getmore'` in the loaded data. Using the deferred/delegate version of `on` should solve it without other changes.

Comment: +1 for providing code and HTML.

Comment: Quite easy, but please ask that as another question as this one is getting cluttered :) Suggest you delete any comments that make no sense (now I have removed mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the deferred syntax of `on` instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.getmore', function...
```

This will survive DOM changes. This answer presumes that your loaded data contains an object with `class="getmore"`, as you are removing it from the DOM on success. If not you need to remove the `remove` as suggested by `NewInTheBusiness`, but probably replace it with `empty()`  instead to remove the loading progress.

*Note I have recently found problems with the version of `on` that only takes the event and function. In jQuery 1.10.3 it seems to not be firing when it should.*

Answer (score 1):

It's because you remove the getmore class after success.

Remove this line of code:

```
$('.getmore').remove();
```

Comment: Loader image displaying on middle of the list after firing the data, and even then its working only for once.

Comment: @Fastnto Since you're adding the image to the same element you use as trigger, you might want to remove the image after success by $('.getmore').html('Click here to fire again') instead of removing it.

Comment: Thanks for thanking me, however this answer is not correct as the loaded data contained an element with `class="getmore"`. Call mine a lucky guess, but I expected that to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

- Check your firebug console for any error
- Remove this line `$('.getmore').remove();`
- [`Delegate`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the click event to the element's `static parent` or to the `document`.

Try,

```
$(document).on("click",'.getmore', function( event ) {

});
```

Comment: This doesn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Just try live or bind in-place of "on" :

```
$('.getmore').live('click',function(){
}
```

or

```
$('.getmore').bind('click',function(){
}
```